# Certbot Apache for Laravel project in subfolder not working

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04

I currently set up ssl certificate for my website using certbot for my apache server running on Ubuntu 16.04. I successfully installed the ssl certificate and now I can access my website by https://example.com

The problem is I have a laravel project I put in the example.com/laravel. When I tried to open the https://example.com/laravel/public i got error 500.

Is it got something to do with the .htaccess in public folder?

Edit:

on my apache log: unexpected '?' in /var/www/html/api_poremo/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php

Comment: just check apache logs, you propably need to enable mod rewrite and enable allowoverride

Comment: @Peter:
I've run the `a2enmod rewrite` and also chane AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in my apache2.conf

Comment: so what logs say

Answer (score 0):

All the errors are on apache logs... and silly me, it got nothing to do with the certbot, the main problem is some of my php package dependencies are missing